# Output of XML into CSV using XSLT not styling correctly

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file with the following

```
    <issues>
          <issue>
             <fieldvalue id="fld1">58</fieldvalue>
         </issue>
          <issue>
                <fieldvalue id="fld1">26</fieldvalue>
          </issue>
          <issue>
                <fieldvalue id="fld1">26</fieldvalue>
          </issue>
```

The numbers of the field values should all be under the issue id like so

```
Issue ID
 58
 Issue ID
 26
 Issue ID
 31
```

But instead I am getting the name of the issue id's/fieldvalue id's horizontally instead of them going under the name Issue ID

```
Issue ID     Subject  Submitted By
    58          26       31
```

My xslt contains this

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="fields">
    <xsl:for-each select="field">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(field_name)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() != last()">,</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="issues">
    <xsl:for-each select="issue">
        <xsl:value-of select="fieldvalue/text()"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() != last()">,</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Your XML is incomplete. Please edit your question and include the data that is missing. Also include your full stylesheet - from the templates you posted there is not enough information about the context to help solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood problem. Issues and Fields are under same parent element. 
We have populate Field Name and Issue Value one by one.

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:for-each select="//issues/issue">
        <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../fields/field[position()=$pos]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="./fieldvalue"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>           
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML used for the above XSL:

```
<xml>
<issues>
<issue>
    <fieldvalue id="fld1">58</fieldvalue>
</issue>
<issue>
    <fieldvalue id="fld1">26</fieldvalue>
</issue>
<issue>
    <fieldvalue id="fld1">31</fieldvalue>
</issue>
</issues>
<fields>
    <field>
        <field_name id="fld1">Issue ID</field_name>
    </field>
    <field>
        <field_name id="fld1">Subject</field_name>
    </field>
    <field>
        <field_name id="fld1">Submitted By</field_name>
    </field>
</fields>
</xml>
```

Output:

```
Issue ID
58
Subject
26
Submitted By
31
```

Comment: Please add comma and position() = last() as per your convinient

Comment: That worked by adding what you suggested. Thank you!